# What does λ[α =>F] mean?

Tags: scalaz, scalaz7, kind-projector

I'm learning Scalaz recently. I would like to know how  λ[α =>F] works?

```
scala> Applicative[λ[α => Int]].point(10)
res45: Int = 0

scala> Applicative[λ[α => String]].point(10)
res46: String = ""
```

I can understand λ means some type here, but I could not find its definition and would like to know how the above code works.

Comment: Lambda that takes a (anything) and returns an Int (first one) or a String (second one). If you come from imperative programming you can think of it as a pointer to a function int foo(Object a) and string foo(Object a). But don't tell functional programmers that you think this way, they tend to get angry.

Comment: Thanks!  I'd like to know how the λ type works,  There must be some code about the λ. Because I could not change  λ to a different name, such as T.  Applicative[T[α => String]].point(10) does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scalaz use kind-projector.

`Applicative[λ[α => Int]]` is equivalent to `Applicative[({type l[a] = Int})#l]`

- https://github.com/non/kind-projector
- https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/875